# Granting mysql access rights to all machines on subnet

Tags: mysql, security, database-permissions, subnet

I have a mysql instance (and schema) running on windows that I can access via a connection string based on localhost as the server.

now I want to be able to access this db from another machine on the same subnet.

If possible I would like to use a single user but allow it to access from any machine on the same subnet.

how do I setup security for this? 
(I already opened the relevant firewall port)

Thanks,
Eyal

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb TO 'username'@'192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0';
```

change subnet and IP accordingly

Comment: I suppose its would not be a good idea to do this on root. do I need to create 'username' some how before this grant statement? and if so, how do I set the password for username ?

Comment: not work for me with Percona XtraDB Cluster 5.7 :-(

Comment: That maybe down to something in their setup you should check their documentation

Comment: For me: for mysql 8: 192.168.1.0/24 works well, but for mysql 5.7 works only 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0

Answer (score 3):

You can also use wildcards, rather than a masks.

> You can specify wildcards in the host name. For example,
>   user_name@'%.example.com' applies to user_name for any host in the
>   example.com domain, and user_name@'192.168.1.%' applies to user_name
>   for any host in the 192.168.1 class C subnet.

See the [Account Names and Passwords section](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) of the in the `GRANT` docs.